# CSS: no top,right and bottom border on a table cells

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a table with the last column cells (and header) having nor right, top and bottom border. I have searched Sobut i am unable to make what I found work,

This fiddle shows what I have tried: https://jsfiddle.net/prtome/taqge61v/

HTML

```
<table class="asktable">
<thead>
<th> col1</th>
<th> col1</th>
<th class="no-border-right"> col no border</th>
</thead>
<tbody><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>cell no border</td></tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.asktable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.asktable th {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.asktable td {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.asktable th.no-border-right{
  border-top:0;
  border-right:0 !important;
  border-bottom:0;
}
```

Where is my error ? thanks for any pointer

Comment: thanks for all the answers. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a border set on the whole table so even with this removed from the `th` and `td` the border will still appear.

Also as a side note, you can do away with the extra classes to remove the border by using `:last-child` and omit the `!important`.

Ive edited your CSS below.

```css
.asktable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.asktable th {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.asktable td {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.asktable th:last-child,
.asktable td:last-child {
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="asktable">
  <thead>
    <th>col1</th>
    <th>col1</th>
    <th class="no-border-right">col no border</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>cell no border</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>
  <br>
</p>

<table class="asktable no-border-right">
  <thead>
    <th>col1</th>
    <th>col1</th>
    <th class="no-border-right">col no border</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>ccell no border</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I knew there was something I was missing. now it works

Answer (score 1):

Use hidden instead of 0, for example:

```
  border-top:hidden !important;
  border-right:hidden !important;
  border-bottom:hidden !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `border-xxx-color:transparent;` where you want no border. It will helps you.

```css
.asktable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.asktable th {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.asktable td {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/*.asktable th.no-border-right{
  border-top-color:transparent !important;
  border-right-color:transparent !important;
  border-bottom-color:transparent !important;
}*/

.asktable .no-border-right{
  border-top-color:transparent !important;
  border-right-color:transparent !important;
  border-bottom-color:transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="asktable">
 <thead>
  <th> col1</th>
  <th> col1</th>
  <th class="no-border-right"> col no border</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>cell no border</td>
 </tbody>
</table>
 <p>
 <br>
 </p>

<table class="asktable no-border-right">
 <thead>
  <th> col1</th>
  <th> col1</th>
  <th  class="no-border-right"> col no border</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>ccell no border</td>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove border to `table`

```
.asktable {
    /*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/taqge61v/8/

Comment: I absolutely missed the border on the table, misunderstood the border-collapse. Learned something, thanks